# How do I remove the part in the bottom and make it not show while zooming out

Tags: html, css

[I want to remove the bottom part, btw look at the blue line, orange lines are not a part of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daVYi.png)

btw click the above link to see what's the problem ^

This is my problem

I tried 'overflow: hidden' in css
i also tried 'overflow-y: hidden'
But the problem aint fixed
so my question is

1. How do I fix this?
2. is it a problem of html or css?
3. can it be fixed by html or css?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Home | Future Toppers</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal"></script>
<style>
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background: #320A28;
}

.bubbles {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
}

.bubbles span {
    position: relative;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #DA4F8E;
    margin: 0 4px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px #CC5D81, 0 0 50px #DA4F8E, 0 0 100px #DA4F8E;
    animation: animate 15s linear infinite;
    animation-duration: calc(120s / var(--i));
}

.bubbles span:nth-child(even) {
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px #D0CCD0, 0 0 50px white, 0 0 100px white;
}

@keyframes animate{
    0% {
        transform: translateY(100vh) scale(0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(-10vh) scale(1);
    }
}

.conatiner {
    width: 1050px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgb(119, 109, 109), -5px -5px 10px rgb(163, 154, 154);
        background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
    backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
    border-radius: 20px;
    border:1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.18);
    box-shadow: 0 8px 32px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
}


.conatiner:hover > .conatiner::after {
  opacity: 1;
}   

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

header{
    display: flex;
}



.label{
    margin: 29px 0 0 5%;
}

.label a{
    color: #D0CCD0;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor:default;
}

.navbar {
    margin-left: 35%;
}

.navbar ul{
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
}

.navbar ul li{
    padding: 15px;
}

.navbar ul li a {
    background: #BD6B73;
    color: #D0CCD0;
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: 0.5s;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 25px #783B4E;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar ul li a:hover {
    width: 200px;
    transition-delay: 0.5s;
}

.navbar ul li a::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border-top: 3px solid #D0CCD0;
    border-right: 3px solid #D0CCD0;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.navbar ul li a:hover::before {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(50px,-50px);
}

.navbar ul li a::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: -50px;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border-top: 3px solid #D0CCD0;
    border-right: 3px solid #D0CCD0;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-50px, 50px);
    transition: 0.5s;
}


.navbar ul li a span {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.body-content{
    display: flex;
}

.body-content .b-title{
    margin-left: 10%;
}

.body-content .b-title h1{
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.body-content .b-title span{
    color: #D0CCD0;
    width: 500px;
    font-size: 40px;
}

.body-content .b-title .icons{

    display: flex;
    margin-top: 80px;
}

.body-content .b-title .icons img{
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.body-content .b-img{
    margin-left: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
}

.body-content .b-img img{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 15px solid #BD6B73;
}

    .Contact {
        width: fit-content;
    }
    
     .head-one {
        font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 50px;
        color: #DA4F8E;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 500px;
    }

    .details {
        font-size: large;
        font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
        color: #511730;
    }

    *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        transition: 0.2s linear;
        font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    }

    .wrapper {
        margin: 10px auto;
        padding: 0 10%;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        text-transform: capitalize;
        margin-top: 9%;
        border-top: 30px solid #D0CCD0;
  background:
    repeating-conic-gradient(#511730 0 45deg,#BD6B73 0 90deg)
    0 0/100px 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

    .head-two {
        color: #D0CCD0;
        font-size: 45px;
        text-align: center;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
        text-shadow: 0 15px 10px #3f3f3f;
        -webkit-text-stroke: black 2px;
    }

    .container {
        display: grid;
        gap: 15px;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(270px, 1fr));

    }

    .box {
        padding: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: #D0CCD0;
        box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }

    .box h3 {
        color: #320A28;
        padding: 10px 0;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    .box p {
        color: #511730;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 1.6;
    }

    .btn {
        color: #D0CCD0;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        font-size: 17px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        padding: 8px 15px;
        background: #783B4E;
        border-radius: 5px;
        display: inline-block;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .btn:hover {
        letter-spacing: 1px;
    }

    .box:hover {
        transform: scale(1.03);
        box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }

    @media (max-width: 770px) {
        .container {
            padding: 20px;
        }
    }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="bubbles">
        <span style="--i:11;"></span>
        <span style="--i:12;"></span>
        <span style="--i:24;"></span>
        <span style="--i:10;"></span>
        <span style="--i:14;"></span>
        <span style="--i:23;"></span>
        <span style="--i:18;"></span>
        <span style="--i:16;"></span>
        <span style="--i:19;"></span>
        <span style="--i:20;"></span>
        <span style="--i:22;"></span>
        <span style="--i:25;"></span>
        <span style="--i:18;"></span>
        <span style="--i:21;"></span>
        <span style="--i:15;"></span>
        <span style="--i:13;"></span>
        <span style="--i:26;"></span>
        <span style="--i:17;"></span>
        <span style="--i:13;"></span>
        <span style="--i:28;"></span>
        <span style="--i:11;"></span>
        <span style="--i:12;"></span>
        <span style="--i:24;"></span>
        <span style="--i:10;"></span>
        <span style="--i:14;"></span>
        <span style="--i:23;"></span>
        <span style="--i:18;"></span>
        <span style="--i:16;"></span>
        <span style="--i:19;"></span>
        <span style="--i:20;"></span>
        <span style="--i:22;"></span>
        <span style="--i:25;"></span>
        <span style="--i:18;"></span>
        <span style="--i:21;"></span>
        <span style="--i:15;"></span>
        <span style="--i:13;"></span>
        <span style="--i:26;"></span>
        <span style="--i:17;"></span>
        <span style="--i:13;"></span>
        <span style="--i:28;"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="conatiner">
      <header>
        <div class="label">
          <a href="#">Future Toppers</a>
        </div>
      </header>
      <div class="body-content">
        <div class="b-title">
          <h1>HELLO,<br />We are<span> Future Toppers</span><br />Tution</h1>
          <div class="icons">
            <img src="Images/WhatsApp.png" />
            <img src="/Images/Instagram.png" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="b-img">
          <img src="Images/FUTURE TOPPERS.png" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h2 class="head-two"> Courses We Provide [CBSE ONLY] </h2>
        <div class="container">
        <div class="box">
            <h3>Grade 12 Biology [RECOMMENDED] </h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn"> Read More </a>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <h3>Grade 12 Chemistry</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn"> Read More </a>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <h3>Grade 11 Biology [RECOMMENDED]</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn"> Read More </a>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <h3>Grade 11 Chemistry</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn"> Read More </a>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <h3>Grade 10 Science <b>(Crash Course) [LIMITED TIME]</b></h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
            <a href="/10-science-cc.html" class="btn"> Read More </a>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <h3>Grade 10 Science</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn"> Read More </a>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <h3>Grade 10 Maths</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn"> Read More </a>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <h3>Grade 10 Social </h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn"> Read More </a>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <h3>Grade 9 All Subjects </h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn"> Read More </a>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <h3>Grade 8 All Subjects</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn"> Read More </a>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <h3>Grade 7 All Subjects </h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn"> Read More </a>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <h3>Grade 6 All Subjects</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn"> Read More </a>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <h3>Grade 5 All Subjects</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn"> Read More </a>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <h3>Grade 4 All Subjects</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn"> Read More </a>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <h3>Grade 3 All Subjects</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn"> Read More </a>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <h3>Grade 2 All Subjects</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn"> Read More </a>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <h3>Grade 1 All Subjects</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn"> Read More </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script class="btn" type="text/javascript" src="/vanilla-tilt.js"></script>
    <script>
    VanillaTilt.init(document.querySelectorAll(".box"), {
        max: 25,
        speed: 400
    });
    </script>
    <script>
        ScrollReveal().reveal('.box', {delay: 300, interval: 150, reset: true,});
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Create a small example here with your code and then we can try to understand your problem. In general we don't post pictures because they will not help us understand the code behind it.